# как реализовать галерею на сайте, что бы клиент мог добавлять свои картинки

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, gallery

я начинающий верстальщик, взял первый заказ на создание простенького сайта, но этот сайт для фотографа, и у меня возник вопрос. Каким образом и через что лучше реализовать на сайте галерею, чтобы клиент сам мог добавлять фото в галерею с описанием и т.д. Я так понимаю, что без админ панели не обойтись, посоветуйте как это реализовать. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: в вашем случае, наверное, лучше использовать какой-нибудь готовый движок/cms

Comment: Присоединяюсь к ThisMan: не изобретайте велосипед (по крайней мере на текущем этапе) - используйте к примеру WordPress. И быстро простенькие сайты поднимать будете, и заодно в исходниках посмотрите как всё реализовано. В противном случае Вы рискуете либо заказ не выполнить, либо система будет вся "дырявая" в плане безопасности и производительности.

Comment: В wordpress мало что можно реализовать без платных плагинов

Comment: Если не хотите использовать готовые решения, тогда вам придется вручную писать серверную часть, что для начинающего верстальщика, мягко говоря, совсем не просто. Тем более когда уже есть конкретные сроки на проект. Берите готовую CMS и делайте сайт на ней, например на уже упомянутой wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько способов:

1. **Написать вручную**. Для этого придется изучить некоторые аспекты не входящие в задачи верстальщика, будет возможно нелегко, интересно, и затратно по времени. Для загрузки файлов функцию можно написать к примеру на PHP (возможно придется вникнуть ещё и в то как создать систему авторизации, чтобы фото грузить мог не абы-кто), данные хранить к примеру в БД MySQL (в основы которой тоже придется вникнуть), отображение можно на JS сделать, либо тоже на PHP. Вообще на том же ютубе есть куча роликов о том как это сделать, гуглим =)
2. **Использовать готовую CMS**. Быстрее и проще чем первый способ, но тут тоже придётся вникнуть в принципы работы. Из плюсов интуитивно понятный графический интерфейс, некоторая защита, всё уже сделано за вас, но в довесок куча мёртвого кода, который используется меньше чем наполовину.
3. **Найти в напарники back-end программиста** - если вы позиционируете себя именно как верстальщик, и подобные задачи передавать ему, самому заниматься лишь вёрсткой. Самый простой и быстрый способ. Из минусов - придётся делиться прибылью :D